# Giving input to a application using AutoHot Key

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to run an application using AutoHot Key. Once the application opens, I need to give 4 characters fixed input but somehow when I press the F11 key, it opens the application but prints "2856" on my notepad and not in application.

F11::
Run "EntrustSoftoken"
SendRaw "2856"
return

Comment: You probably need to set EntrustSoftoken as the active window before sending the keys.

Answer (score 1):

"Run "EntrustSoftoken" is not a valid command.  If is a standalone application, it would have to be something like 'Run EntrustSoftoken.exe' among other things.... but you also need things like winwait and winactivate to ensure it targets the right window before sending the string '2856'.

You probably have your computer set to use notepad for unidentified programs ((Right click something -> Open With -> Choose program - is probably set to Notepad, which is why notepad opened))